# Effect sizes for $\chi^2$ tests when $df > 1$

Tags: chi-squared-test, effect-size

[Rosenberg (2010)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0010059) discusses the [Phi coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) measure of effect size for $\chi^2$:

$r = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{n}}$,

"where the $\chi^2$ value comes from a two-group contrasts (thus a single degree of freedom), and n is the total number of samples; the sign of the correlation needs to be determined from independent study of the contrast."

Rosenberg criticizes use of the Phi coefficient for meta-analysis on the grounds it “has an underlying, never-stated assumption which is sometimes violated, particularly for genetics studies: it assumes that the expected values from the $\chi^2$ test are equal for both groups.” Instead Rosenberg advocates the general conversion form $r = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{nk}}$. Here $k$ refers to a ratio of expected values for the two groups $k:1$, where $k$ is the larger group. Thus the general formula would reduce to the regular Phi coefficient if $k=1$.

In passing Rosenberg mentions that:

> $\chi^2$ tests with more than one degree of freedom are unfocused
> omnibus tests, and require a much more complicated procedure for
> conversion to an effect size.

Rosenberg refers readers to Rosenthal and Rosnow (1985), Rosenthal and Rosnow (1991), and Rosenthal, Rosnow, and Rubin (2000) for further details. However, I don’t have access to any of those books, and what meta-commentary (e.g. Boik, 2001) I’ve read has generally been fairly dismissive of the Rosenthal/Rosnow approach, which makes me wonder how helpful the books would be in any case.

My reason for interest in this question is that I'm looking to conduct a meta-analysis in which I aggregate effect sizes from $F$, $t$, and $\chi^2$ tests. The
paper Open Science Foundation (2015) proposes a general framework for doing this, as explained in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484418/the-correlation-coefficient-per-df-effect-size-measure). However, in relation to $\chi^2$ tests they propose only the Phi coefficient, which will only work if $df=1$. Therefore I am looking for a correlation-based effect size that will be compatible with the other effect sizes mentioned in that Open Science Foundation (2015) paper.

My questions are:

1. Is there a procedure for converting $\chi^2$ tests to an effect size when $df > 1$, that would be compatible with the Phi coefficient and the other correlation-based measures mentioned by Open Science Foundation (2015)?
2. Does the procedure also suffer from the problem Rosenberg identified regarding an assumption the expected values from the $\chi^2$ test are equal for all groups? If so, is there any good way to get around that problem?
3. Is the procedure limited to particular applications of the $\chi^2$ test, e.g. limited to analyses of contingency tables?

Boik, R. J. (2001). Contrasts and effect sizes in behavioral research: A correlational approach. *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 96(456), 1528.
Rosenberg, M. S. (2010). A generalized formula for converting chi-square tests to effect sizes for meta-analysis. *PloS one*, 5(4), e10059.
Rosenthal, R., & Rosnow, R. L. (1985). *Contrast analysis: Focused comparisons in the analysis of variance.* CUP Archive.
Rosenthal, R., & Rosnow, R. L. (1991). *Essentials of Behavioral Research: Methods and Data Analysis.* McGraw-Hill.
Rosenthal, R., Rosnow, R. L., & Rubin, D. B. (2000). *Contrasts and effect sizes in behavioral research: A correlational approach*. Cambridge University Press.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V describes one attempt at moving from a $\chi^2$ test to a measure of association

Comment: This is a really good point - somehow I'd forgotten about Cramér's $V$! This may well be the answer. Does anyone know if for the purposes of meta-analysis Cramér's $V$ (for situations where $df>1$) can be aggregated with the Phi coefficient (for situations where $df=1$)? I would have thought so, since in the case of a $2 \times 2$ contingency table Cramér's $V$ is equal to the Phi coefficient.

Comment: $V$ is calculated from $\phi$. If there are only two columns *or* only two rows in a contingency table then $V=\phi$.