# Non-normal residuals when the outcome variable is a Fisher $Z$-transformed correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, normality-assumption

I’m running a multilevel model in which the outcome variable is a Fisher Z-transformed correlation coefficient. The residuals look quite non-normal:

[image: QQ plot of non-normal residuals]

In case the details matter, I’ll mention that the model in question is model ‘1’ described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/460826/what-s-the-right-multilevel-model-to-address-this-meta-analysis)

Though I'm not sure how concerning this is in absolute terms, it's far more non-normal than I'd previously seen when previously doing classical or multilevel regression. However, typically I don't use outcome variables that have been transformed in this way.

I'm wondering the following:

Was the non-normality of the residuals an inevitable (or highly likely) consequence of my choice of outcome variable. If so, why?

What, if anything, should I do about this issue? I’m weighing the pros and cons of doing nothing as against applying a further transformation.

In terms of how concerned I should be about this issue, is there any reason I should be more/less concerned seeing this happen with a multilevel regression model than I would be if I was doing a classical regression model and saw the same level of non-normality of residuals? I’m aware that, [as per this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152674/why-is-the-normality-of-residuals-barely-important-at-all-for-the-purpose-of-e), in linear models in general the normality of residuals is “barely important at all” for the purpose of estimating the regression line.

Edit: As per @nick-cox's comment, I've pasted a few histograms below indicating the distribution of the original correlations and of the Fisher-transformed correlations. The reason all the correlations are positive is that the correlations are measures of effect size. I've also shared the data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tjm5vjuLnKkoQW7E8DeooF5H98d6r7b-VCmeo17HgbU/edit?usp=sharing).

[image: Untransformed correlations]

[image: Transformed correlations]

Comment: Can you post plots of the distribution of the original correlations and their transforms?

Comment: Thanks, I just posted histograms of the original correlations and the Fisher-transformed correlations, and also a link to the data (raw residuals, original correlations, and Fisher-transformed correlations). I could certainly post more/other plots or more data if it would be helpful.

Comment: So, the transformation makes things worse. I've not wanted to use correlation as an outcome variable, but for once I would prefer -- on this information -- to use it directly. A linear model in principle might predict values for $r$ outside $[-1, 1]$ but my guess is that you won't be bitten by that in practice.

Comment: Even a prediction outside $[0,1]$ would be problematic since the correlations are effect sizes and can only be positive. Originally I thought to use a Beta mixed model, as per [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233366/how-to-fit-a-mixed-model-with-response-variable-between-0-and-1), but in $\frac{5}{2032}$ of my cases $r=0$. Workarounds are suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48028/beta-regression-of-proportion-data-including-1-and-0) but it seems a bit complicated. Do you think a Beta mixed model would be preferable to using $r$ as the outcome?

Comment: I disagree. A prediction of a negative correlation tells you about what your data are saying. Not letting the data tell you about a problem is quite different from not letting a model predict an impossibility. I don't know enough about beta mixed models to advise otherwise.